# How to configure a default set of properties to be used in every new Maven project?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm learning Maven and writing a simple PowerShell script to quickly create a project from the command-line. I've noticed that when creating a project with the line:

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DgroupId=my.group.id" "-DartifactId=my-project" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.4" "-DinteractiveMode=false"
```

the following properties are present:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

I wanted my new projects to have this properties instead:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

I've tried adding a `"-Dmaven.compiler.release=11"`, but that didn't work. Adding the profile:

```
<profile>
      <id>jdk-11</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>11</jdk>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
      </properties>
</profile>
```

to the *settings.xml* file didn't help either.

Is there a way I can do this without having to manually modify the *pom.xml* file every time I create a project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you'll need to create a archetype project (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) and configure the compiler information there. Alternatively since you're doing this with a powershell script I think you could add some code to manipulate the XML after `mvn archetype:generate` runs

Comment: Yes. You need create your own maven achetype and use it in future.